# How to bring php5 in yocto image?

Tags: yocto, php-5.6, bitbake

In my yocto development kit I included meta-openembedded/meta-oe in conf/bblayer.conf for meta-raspberrypi but I can't able to see php5 at the final image in /etc/php.I tried giving **bitbake php** and also included **IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " php"** nothing works.Can anyone please help me to include it in final image.

Comment: which yocto branch your using

Comment: poky-sumo branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bydefault `Poky-sumo` branch gives `php7.2` and if you want php5 use
 `PREFERED_PROVIDER_VERSION_php ="5.6.35"`

Below are the packages provided by php recipe

```
PACKAGES = "${PN}-dbg ${PN}-cli ${PN}-cgi ${PN}-fpm ${PN}-fpm-apache2 ${PN}-pear ${PN}-phar ${MODPHP_PACKAGE} ${PN}-dev ${PN}-staticdev ${PN}-doc ${PN}
```

you can all all required above packages like below example.

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " php-cli php-cgi php-pear"
```

Comment: I tried adding PREFERED_PROVIDER_VERSION_php ="5.6.35" in local.conf and also included the php-cli,php-cgi also but nothing works for me,in /etc/php-> is not appearing.But in /usr/bin I can see php and php-cgi file alone.

Comment: yes I tried these **php-staticdev php-dev php-dbg php-doc php-dbg php-cli php-cgi php-pear**

Answer (score 0):

You might find it's installed just not as you are expecting. Using Yocto version Sumo and the [meta-oe php 7.2.10][1] I added PHP to my image using:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "php php-cli php-fpm"
```

I found it bitbaked and installed fine but didn't generate the /etc/php folder or php.ini.

To see if it is installed:

```
php -v
```

Once you are in your OS create a file test.php and in it add:

```
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

Then run the below tells you the path it is expecting php.ini:

```
php test.php | grep php.ini
```